# angular: Newlines in are not printed in paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textarea, newline

I am trying to show text from a text-area in a '< p >' tag.
The newlines are ignored when the output is printed in the < p > tag.

```
Check following:
```

[JSF](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/31586/)

using angular for databinding

How can I make the < p > tag to print the newlines?

Comment: You code is right just left .lines for class see this https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/31589/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `white-space: pre;` on your `lines class` (please note you have missed a dot referencing your class in the CSS file.

### [JSF](https://jsfiddle.net/z5rLd1mz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Apply `white-space:pre-wrap;` property in lines class  properly .

```
.lines {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }
```

It is working for me.